# Angular 5 Owl carousel How to increase / decrease rotating speed

Tags: angular, owl-carousel

I'm using Owl Carousel in Angular5 and want to increase or decrease the sliding speed however, I can't find any option.

in the module.ts file,

```
import { OwlModule } from 'ngx-owl-carousel';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        OwlModule],
    exports: [OwlModule],
```

In .html file:

```
<owl-carousel [options]="{items: 1, dots: false, loop:true, autoplay:true, nav: true, responsive: { '0': { nav: false, dots: true}, '1200': { nav: true, dots: false}}}"
         [items]="bannerImages" [carouselClasses]="['owl-theme', 'row', 'sliding']">
            <div class="item" *ngFor="let image of bannerImages">
                <!-- <div class="image" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url('+image.imagePath+')'}"></div> -->
                <div class="image">
                    <img [src]="image.imagePath">
                    <!-- caption start -->
                    <div class="container caption h-100 d-flex">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col caption-content" [innerHTML]="image.bannerContent"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- caption end -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </owl-carousel>
```

I've gone through the document https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-owl-carousel and see that there is an option `next`. But how can I implement this? My intention is to increase / decrease the sliding speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should check native owl-carousel options
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

And provide `navSpeed`. Smth like this

```
<owl-carousel [options]="{items: 1, ..., navSpeed: 200}"
...
```

Comment: I added this but no change.

Comment: How do you navigate? Swiping or dots clicking or next/prev buttons?

Comment: I'm using Autoplay

Comment: Oh, in this case you should use `autoplaySpeed` option I think